# Long running publisher in rabbitmq

Tags: jakarta-ee, rabbitmq, messaging, amqp

What is the best approach to create a long lived publisher in rabbitmq?
The goal is to use the same producer for multiple messages in different classes.
I want to avoid creating a new connection and new channel for each message.

Comment: Are you using a library for RabbitMQ, such a Spring? These libraries have these capabilities built in.

Comment: I have to use the RabbitMQ java client.

Comment: Are you using Spring too?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to avoid creating a new connection and new channel for each message.

Did you try just not doing that, and keeping the old connection and corresponding channel alive? You can create a helper/singleton class for that. As for the closure of both channel and connection, you'd probably need to override `finalize` for that. [See this topic for more info on destructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171952/is-there-a-destructor-for-java)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using IOC to handle this for you.  Setup the IConnection as a singleton (see this post for help with that https://stackoverflow.com/a/30032001/1173800) and then each time you instantiate your IProducer it will handle re-using the connection for you.